# Перенести код в другой файл

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Есть файл edit.php который отвечает за редактирование данных, в нём подключаю javascript в коде которого передаётся url на другой файл(update.php). В update.php я вставляю php код из файла edit.php ,но код в update.php не работает.Как правильно перенести код?

edit.php  полностью:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>редактирование клиента</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- include the script -->
    <script src="alertifyjs/alertify.min.js"></script>
    <!-- include the style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="alertifyjs/css/alertify.min.css"/>
    <!-- include a theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="alertifyjs/css/themes/default.min.css"/>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("document").ready(function () {
            $("form").submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault(); // !!!
                var dannie = $("form").serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'update.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: dannie,
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data) {
                            alertify.set('notifier', 'position', 'top-right');
                            alertify.success('Клиент успешно Отредактирова!');
                        }
                        else {
                            alertify.alert("Ошибка");
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<?php
include_once("db1.php");
$id = $_GET['id'];
if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
    $klient = strip_tags(trim($_POST['klient']));
    $op_firma = strip_tags(trim($_POST['op_forma']));
    $naimen = strip_tags(trim($_POST['naimen']));
    $otrasl = strip_tags(trim($_POST['otrasl']));
    $telefon = strip_tags(trim($_POST['telefon']));
    $email = strip_tags(trim($_POST['email']));
    $kont_lico = strip_tags(trim($_POST['kont_lico']));
    $dolznost = strip_tags(trim($_POST['dolznost']));
    mysql_query("
        UPDATE klienti SET klient='$klient', op_forma='$op_firma', naimen='$naimen',otrasl='$otrasl',telefon='$telefon',email='$email',kont_lico='$kont_lico',dolznost='$dolznost' WHERE id='$id' 
               ");
}
$rezult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM klienti WHERE id='$id' ");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rezult);
mysql_close();
?>
<form method="post" action="edit.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" id="form">
    клиент<br/>
    <input type="text" name="klient" value="<?php echo $row['klient']; ?>"/> <br/>

    ОП_форма <br/>
    <input type="text" name="op_forma" value="<?php echo $row['op_forma']; ?>"/> <br/> <!-- cols="10" rows="10" -->

    Наимен <br/>
    <input type="text" name="naimen" value="<?php echo $row['naimen']; ?>"/><br/><br/>
    отрасль <br/>
    <input type="text" name="otrasl" value="<?php echo $row['otrasl']; ?>"/><br/><br/>
    telefon <br/>
    <input type="text" name="telefon" value="<?php echo $row['telefon']; ?>"/><br/><br/>
    email <br/>
    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $row['email']; ?>"/><br/><br/>
    ОП фирмы <br/>
    <input type="text" name="kont_lico" value="<?php echo $row['kont_lico']; ?>"/><br/><br/>
    ОП фирмы <br/>
    <input type="text" name="dolznost" value="<?php echo $row['dolznost']; ?>"/><br/><br/>
    <input type="hidden" name="date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="time" value="<?php echo date('H:i:s'); ?>"/>
    <input type="submit" name="save" value="Сохранить"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Прописываю в update php вот это:

```
  <?php
include_once("db1.php");
$id = $_GET['id'];
if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
    $klient = strip_tags(trim($_POST['klient']));
    $op_firma = strip_tags(trim($_POST['op_forma']));
    $naimen = strip_tags(trim($_POST['naimen']));
    $otrasl = strip_tags(trim($_POST['otrasl']));
    $telefon = strip_tags(trim($_POST['telefon']));
    $email = strip_tags(trim($_POST['email']));
    $kont_lico = strip_tags(trim($_POST['kont_lico']));
    $dolznost = strip_tags(trim($_POST['dolznost']));
    mysql_query("
        UPDATE klienti SET klient='$klient', op_forma='$op_firma', naimen='$naimen',otrasl='$otrasl',telefon='$telefon',email='$email',kont_lico='$kont_lico',dolznost='$dolznost' WHERE id='$id' 
               ");
}
$rezult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM klienti WHERE id='$id' ");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rezult);
mysql_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Неправильный URL `url: 'update.php',`, надо переписать

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    $("form").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var form = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr("action"),
            type: 'POST',
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    alertify.set('notifier', 'position', 'top-right');
                    alertify.success('Клиент успешно Отредактирова!');
                } else {
                    alertify.alert("Ошибка");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Переписал,алерт появился,но данные не изменились,что может быть?

Comment: проверь результат выполнения запроса UPDATE. там нет ошибки?
и еще, сама форма точно передает данные? проверь `print_r($_POST)`
и заголовок формы проверь. такой?
`<form method="post" action="update.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" id="form">`

Comment: Заголовок формы исправил,спасибо. Запрос проверил,правильный. Но вот не работает всё равно, алерт выскакивает, а данные не передаются(проверил как ты сказал print_r($_POST) ).Если закоментить строку `$("document").ready(function () {` то в `$_POST` всё передаётся и работает,но тогда алерт не выскакивает. Что может быть ещё не так?)

Comment: а у тебя больше никаких форм на странице нет? потому что тогда нужно `$("#form").submit()`, или немножко по-другому посылать запрос